# "" Excel 2010 List of values - VLOOKUP MATCH

Tags: excel, vlookup

"" Excel 2010 List of values - if one value in column A matches value in column B then set the first value of colum C ""

CELL A1: d4124985 CELL B: Should be used for results CELL C1: d2017985 CELL D1 d4125985 CELL D2: d4125985 Cell A1 and Cell C1 are connected (old value and new value). The formula should check if in the Cells D1 or D2 (or the whole column) is a match of A1 and write the result in B1

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant for either D1 or D2 to match A1, but in any case.

This should work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,D:D,1,0),"Not Found")
```

Assuming you wanted to pull back the matching value and not just an indicator that their was a match.

If you're looking for an indicator of if a match was found this should work:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,D:D,0),0)>0,"Match Found","No Match Found")
```

Ok, that's a little different than I originially understood.

For that you'll need to use "=INDEX()" and "=MATCH()" like so:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,D:D,0),1)
```

VLOOKUP can only pull values from the right of the matching value. To pull from the left of the matching value you use MATCH to find the value and then INDEX to pull the value.

Comment: Yes I want the formula to check if a math in colum D was found and paste the connected value from colum C ind colum B

Comment: See my revised suggestion above.